# Почему получаю IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, android

Есть у меня такой метод

```
public synchronized void setProgress(final int progress, final boolean fromUser) {
    if (mMethodSetProgress == null) {
        try {
            Method m;
            m = this.getClass().getMethod("setProgress", int.class, boolean.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            mMethodSetProgress = m;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
        }
    }

    if (mMethodSetProgress != null) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mMethodSetProgress.invoke(this, progress, fromUser);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    } else {
        super.setProgress(progress);
    }
    refreshThumb();
}
```

и почему то вылетаю в `catch()` с ошибкой

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7222
                                                                                  Process: com.example.android.camera2basic, PID: 20402
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar, but got com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar$1
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar$1.run(VerticalSeekBar.java:310)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Подскажите, что не так?

Дополнение

```
android.widget.ProgressBar.invalidateDrawable(ProgressBar.java:1673)
06-30 18:37:11.048 8729-10663/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:408)
06-30 18:37:11.048 8729-10823/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar$1.run(VerticalSeekBar.java:309)
06-30 18:37:11.048 8729-10823/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-30 18:37:11.048 8729-10776/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err: Caused by:     at 
06-30 18:37:11.048 8729-10472/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err: Caused by:     at 
06-30 18:37:11.048 8729-10840/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:    at 
06-30 18:37:11.048 8729-10840/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar$1.run(VerticalSeekBar.java:309)
06-30 18:37:11.058 8729-10731/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err: android.widget.ProgressBar.invalidateDrawable(ProgressBar.java:1673)
06-30 18:37:11.058 8729-10731/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4946)
06-30 18:37:11.058 8729-10731/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:12576)
06-30 18:37:11.058 8729-10731/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:12512)
06-30 18:37:11.058 8729-10735/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7062)
06-30 18:37:11.058 8729-10735/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1022)
06-30 18:37:11.058 8729-10753/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err: android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7062)  at 
06-30 18:37:11.058 8729-10753/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1022)
06-30 18:37:11.058 8729-10753/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4946)
06-30 18:37:11.058 8729-10730/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar$1.run(VerticalSeekBar.java:309)  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7062)android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:408)
```

Comment: Приводите пожалуйста логи как код а не как цитату, читать неудобно

Comment: @xkor ок. Мне казалось так удобнее)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в строчке `mMethodSetProgress.invoke(this, progress, fromUser);` у вас в this будет анонимная реализация Runnable а не VerticalSeekBar. Надо так: `mMethodSetProgress.invoke(VerticalSeekBar.this, progress, fromUser);`

Дело в том что когда вы пишите `new Runnable() {` вы начинаете писать реализацию вложенного анонимного класса наследующегося от `Runnable` и соответственно пока вы внутри этой реализации ключевое слово `this` будет ассоциироваться именно с этим вложенным классом. Запись `VerticalSeekBar.this` же указывает что вы хотитете обратиться к текущему экземпляру именно VerticalSeekBar. Такая запись работает только во вложенных в VerticalSeekBar классах, ну ещё в нем самом, но там она бессмысленна.

Comment: Да так и есть...Я правде не понял почему, но заработало... Ну всмысле эта ошибка теперь не показывается, но теперь другая показалась я дополнил в вопрос, может и с ней подскажите?

Comment: Что то я в вашей новой ошибке не вижу какое сообщение об ошибке то, только её стектрейс. Да и тот какой то покоцаный что ли

Comment: Блин, ну как таковой фатальной ошибки там нет, но в итоге метод не работает... То наверное нужно полностью смотреть код... Ладно буду дальше тестировать, думаю найду что не так